# Calcular valores de inputs y agregar los resultados a otros input en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy recogiendo valores de varios input, para luego procesarlos y obtener dos resultados. Esos dos resultados los quiero mostrar en dos input direfentes pero no sucede nada al momento de llamar a la funcion "calcular()" con el evento onclick de javascript.

Aqui el codigo:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <form  method="GET" action="{{ url('registrarVentas') }}">

        <p class="display h2 text-center">REGISTRO DE VENTAS</p>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <table class="table table-dark">
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Cantidad Total</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberCantidad" value="cantidad" name="numberCantidad" required >
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Fecha</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2019-05-11')) ?>" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Importe Total</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberImportetotal" value="importetotal" name="numberImportetotal" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>Nit</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberImportetotal" value="importetotal" name="numberImportetotal" required >
                            </div></div></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>Cliente</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textCliente" value="nombre_cliente" name="textCliente" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>Vendedor</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textVendedor" value="persona_id" name="texVendedor" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <table class="table table-dark">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="bg-danger">

                            <td>Productos</td>
                            <td>Precio/Unidad</td>
                            <td>Cantidad</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Pan casero</td>
                                <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                <td><input type="number" id="PanCasero" min="0" name="radio" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Marrraqueta</td>
                            <td class="text-center">3</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Marrraqueta" name="Marrraqueta" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Pan Frances</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Pan Frances" name="PanFrances" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Roscas</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Roscas" name="Roscas" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>

                            <td>Pan Galleta</td>
                            <td class="text-center">1</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="PanGalleta" name="PanGalleta" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="text-white">Mollete</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Mollete" name="Mollete" value="0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="text-white">Pan con Harina</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0"  id="PanConHarina" name="PanConHarina" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="text-right"><input type="button" onclick="calcular()" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Insertar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Borrar</button>
        </div>


    </form>
      </div>

<script>
                function calcular() {

                        var Pan_casero = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanCasero").value);
                        var Marrraqueta = parseInt(document.getElementById("Marraqueta")value);
                        var Pan_Frances = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanFrances")value);
                        var Roscas = parseInt(document.getElementById("Roscas").value);
                        var Pan_Galleta = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanGalleta").value);
                        var Mollete = parseInt(document.getElementById("Mollete")value);
                        var Pan_con_Harina = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanConHarina").value);
                        document.write(Pan_con_Harina);
                    if(Pan_casero!=0 || Marrraqueta!=0 || Pan_Frances!=0 || Roscas!=0 || Pan_Galleta!=0 || Mollete!=0 || Pan_con_Harina!=0){ 
                        var cantidad=Pan_casero+Marrraqueta+Pan_Frances+Roscas+Pan_Galleta+Mollete+Pan_con_Harina;
                        var ImporteTotal=(Pan_casero*1)+(Marrraqueta*3)+(Pan_Frances*2)+(Roscas*2)+(Pan_Galleta*1)+(Mollete*2)+(Pan_con_Harina*2);

                        document.getElementById("numberCantidad").value = cantidad;
                        document.getElementById("numberImportetotal").value = ImporteTotal;
                    }else{

                    }
                }
</script>
</body>
```

Aqui les paso una imagen para comprender mejor el problema que tengo:
A la derecha de la imagen los input que recogere y calculare con la funcion calcular() y a la izquierda encerrado con circulos azul donde quiero que vayan las dos variables calculadas en la funcion, cada variable en cada input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores de escritura en tu código, por ejemplo falta el "." antes del `value` en tu `javascript` al querer encontrar algunos `inputs` en base a su id, ademas tienes "Pan frances" como id, y deben de ser exactamente iguales en el `javascript` que en el `html`, por qué el `getElementById`, busca un elemento html en base a su id, por lo tanto deben de ser idénticos, para que pueda encontrarlos.

Aquí tu codigo corregido:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
     <form  method="GET" action="{{ url('registrarVentas') }}">

        <p class="display h2 text-center">REGISTRO DE VENTAS</p>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <table class="table table-dark">
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Cantidad Total</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberCantidad" value="cantidad" name="numberCantidad" required >
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Fecha</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2019-05-11')) ?>" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Importe Total</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberImportetotal" value="importetotal" name="numberImportetotal" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>Nit</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberImportetotal" value="importetotal" name="numberImportetotal" required >
                            </div></div></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>Cliente</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textCliente" value="nombre_cliente" name="textCliente" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>Vendedor</td>
                            <td><div class="col-auto"><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textVendedor" value="persona_id" name="texVendedor" required>
                            </div></div></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                <table class="table table-dark">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="bg-danger">

                            <td>Productos</td>
                            <td>Precio/Unidad</td>
                            <td>Cantidad</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Pan casero</td>
                                <td class="text-center">1</td>
                                <td><input type="number" id="PanCasero" min="0" name="radio" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Marrraqueta</td>
                            <td class="text-center">3</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Marraqueta" name="Marraqueta" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Pan Frances</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="PanFrances" name="PanFrances" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Roscas</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Roscas" name="Roscas" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>

                            <td>Pan Galleta</td>
                            <td class="text-center">1</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="PanGalleta" name="PanGalleta" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="text-white">Mollete</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0" id="Mollete" name="Mollete" value="0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="text-white">Pan con Harina</td>
                            <td class="text-center">2</td>
                            <td><input type="number"  min="0"  id="PanConHarina" name="PanConHarina" value="0" ></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="text-right"><input type="button" onclick="calcular()" class="btn btn-success" value="Agregar"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Insertar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Borrar</button>
        </div>


    </form>
      </div>

<script>
                function calcular() {

                        var Pan_casero = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanCasero").value);
                        var Marrraqueta = parseInt(document.getElementById("Marraqueta").value);
                        var Pan_Frances = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanFrances").value);
                        var Roscas = parseInt(document.getElementById("Roscas").value);
                        var Pan_Galleta = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanGalleta").value);
                        var Mollete = parseInt(document.getElementById("Mollete").value);
                        var Pan_con_Harina = parseInt(document.getElementById("PanConHarina").value);
                        document.write(Pan_con_Harina);
                    if(Pan_casero!=0 || Marrraqueta!=0 || Pan_Frances!=0 || Roscas!=0 || Pan_Galleta!=0 || Mollete!=0 || Pan_con_Harina!=0){ 
                        var cantidad=Pan_casero+Marrraqueta+Pan_Frances+Roscas+Pan_Galleta+Mollete+Pan_con_Harina;
                        var ImporteTotal=(Pan_casero*1)+(Marrraqueta*3)+(Pan_Frances*2)+(Roscas*2)+(Pan_Galleta*1)+(Mollete*2)+(Pan_con_Harina*2);

                        document.getElementById("numberCantidad").value = cantidad;
                        document.getElementById("numberImportetotal").value = ImporteTotal;
                    }else{

                    }
                }
</script>
</body>
```

No se si tu `javascript` hace lo que tu necesitas, pero ya con esto debería de dejar de darte errores.

Te recomiendo usar la consola de tu navegador presionando F12, esta te indicara los errores que hay en tu código `javascript`

Comment: Es verdad, tenia algunos errores, ya me funciona gracias por la analizar el codigo